# cmake not using boost multithreaded libraries

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, cmake

I've `set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)`  But it still doesn't use `-mt` libraries.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(app)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem program_options thread serialization REQUIRED)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(app long_list_of_files)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(app ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

I can see serialization process is using only one CPU core (100%) and not using others. and also ldd doesn't show `-mt` libraries

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb781f000)
libboost_filesystem.so.1.42.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_filesystem.so.1.42.0 (0xb77e9000)
libboost_program_options.so.1.42.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.42.0 (0xb7795000)
libboost_thread.so.1.42.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0 (0xb7780000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7766000)
libboost_serialization.so.1.42.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.42.0 (0xb76f3000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb7608000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb75e2000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb75c5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb7468000)
libboost_system.so.1.42.0 => /usr/lib/libboost_system.so.1.42.0 (0xb7463000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xb745a000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7820000)
```

Comment: what do you get for the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so`?

Comment: Yes the file exists `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 2012-01-27 21:43 /usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.42.0`

Comment: so you are getting the correct version. ldd will show you the actual shared object it is using, not the symlink to it.

Comment: but when My program serializes (using boost serializer) I see only one CPU thread is being used (100%)

Comment: Boost Serialization does not employ threads under the hood. So just by using the library, you should not see more than the number of threads you already spawn yourself.

Comment: In general, compiling and using boost in its multi-threaded mode only makes the library thread-safe (e.g. you can call its functions from different threads). It does *not* result in multi-threaded implementations of each library's functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Boost Serialization aims at providing thread-safety, but not concurrent serialization via threads.**

When installing Boost via a package manager, you will often find library aliases in `/usr/lib` that map a more verbose name of the library to a canonical one. In the case of Boost, the "tagged" name includes the multi-threading ability via the `-mt` suffix.

`ldd` displays only the name used by CMake when it invoked the linker, which is the canonical one and not the verbose one with the `*-mt` suffix. Because your Boost package installation involved the creation of symlinks of the form

```
/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.42.0
```

you should not need to worry about the wrong libraries being linked.

In fact, Boost Serialization does not spawn threads by itself, so you should not see an increased number of threads just by using the library. Internally, the serialization library uses a mutex to protect the counter of a shared pointer.